# Problems with nested object in functional object of the tbb::flow::graph

Tags: c++, tbb, tbb-flow-graph

I have a functional object that I'm using as body for multifunction_node:

```
class module
{
private:
    bool valid;

    QString description;

    bool hasDetectionBranch;
    tDataDescription bufData;

    void* dllObject; //<-- This is a pointer to an object constructed with help of the external dll

    qint64 TimeOut;

public:

    module(const QString& _ExtLibName);
    virtual ~module();

    void operator() (pTransmitData _transmitData, multi_node::output_ports_type &op);
};
```

'dllObject' is created at construction time of the object 'module':

```
module::module(const QString& _ExtLibName) :
    valid(true), hasDetectionBranch(false)
{
    GetObjectDescription = (tGetObjectDescription)QLibrary::resolve(_ExtLibName, "GetObjectDescription");
    CreateObject = (tCreateObject)QLibrary::resolve(_ExtLibName, "CreateObject");
    DestroyObject = (tDestroyObject)QLibrary::resolve(_ExtLibName, "DestroyObject");

    if (!CreateObject || !DestroyObject || !GetObjectDescription)
        valid = false;
    else
    {
        description = QString(GetObjectDescription());
        dllObject = CreateObject();
    }
}
```

And this is when 'dllObject' is destroyed:

```
module::~module()
{
    if (valid)
    {
        DestroyObject(dllObject);
    }
}
```

I've built a little graph:

```
void MainWindow::goBabyClicked(void)
{
    module mod(QString("my.dll")); //<-- Here is OK and mod.dllObject is correct
    if (!mod.isValid())
    {
        qDebug() << "mod is invalid!\n";
        return;
    }

    first fir(input);
    folder fol(QString("C:/out"), 10000);

    graph g;

    source_node<pTransmitData> src(g, fir, false);

    multi_node mnode(g, tbb::flow::serial, mod); //<-- WTF? ~module() is executed!

    function_node<pTransmitData> f(g, tbb::flow::serial, fol);

    make_edge(src, mnode);
    make_edge(mnode, f);

    src.activate();

    g.wait_for_all();
}
```

So I have 2 questions:
1) Why ~module() is executed and how to prevent this?
2) How to keep pointer for nested object correctly?

**UPDATE** Added some dummy code to prevent destroying dllObject at first time like:

```
bool b = false;
module::~module()
{
    if (valid && b)
    {
        DestroyObject(dllObject);
    }
    if (!b)
        b = true;
    valid = false;
}
```

Now it works as expected but looks ugly :/

Comment: What is `multi_node`? I'm not familiar with TBB Flow Graph but I tried looking for it. The class with the closest name I found was [`multifunction_node`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max,

I assume you have a `typedef` of `multi_node` which is similar to the one in the reference manual example.

The constructor for the `multifunction_node` has the following signature:

```
multifunction_node( graph &g, size_t concurrency, Body body );
```

The body object is copied during the parameter passing and also during the construction of the node, so there are two copies of `mod` created during construction (actually three, as an initial copy of the body is also stored for re-initializing the body when calling `reset()` with `rf_reset_bodies`).  The destructor calls you are seeing are probably those used to destroy the copies.

The body object should also have a copy-constructor defined or be able to accept the default-copy-constructor to make copies of the body.  I think the `QString` has a copy-constructor defined, but I don't know about fields like `tDataDescription`.  (I thought we had covered the basic requirements for Body objects in the Reference Manual, but I am still looking for the section.)  In any case, the Body class must be CopyConstructible, as it is copied multiple times.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Mike found the reference; it is in the Reference Guide, under Flow Graph, the page on multifunction_node that has the requirements for the body.  It is repeated for continue_node, function_node and source_node, the nodes which use the Body.